# How can I select a bokeh circle glyphs with a python callback?

Tags: python, bokeh, interactive

I am running a bokeh server with a simple circle glyph and a TapTool to select individual circles.

Now I want to have a button to select all glyphs and update the selection in the plot.

Here is my atempt:

```
from bokeh import plotting as bplt
from bokeh import layouts as blayouts
from bokeh import models as bmodels
from bokeh import io as bio
from bokeh.server.server import Server

fig = bplt.figure(tools="tap")

source = bmodels.ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[0,1], y=[0,1]))

r = fig.circle('x', 'y', source=source, size=10)

def handler(attr, old, new):
    print('attr: {} old: {} new: {}'.format(attr, old, new))

# r.data_source.on_change('selected', handler)
r.data_source.selected.on_change('indices', handler)

button = bmodels.Button(label="select all", button_type="success", width=200)

def callback(event):
    '''Here I would like to select all points in the plot with python code'''

    # this is my atempt:
    print('event: {}'.format(event))
    print('data source selected:', r.data_source.selected.indices)

    r.data_source.selected.indices = [0]

    print('data source selected:', r.data_source.selected.indices)

button.on_click(callback)

def modify(doc):
    layout = blayouts.row(fig, button)
    doc.add_root(layout)
    doc.title = "title"
    print('modify', type(doc))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Opening Bokeh application on http://localhost:5006/')
    server = Server({'/': modify}, num_procs=1)
    server.start()
    server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
    server.io_loop.start()
```

You can run the example just by using:

```
python3 example_code.py
```

My question now is the following: How can I select all Bokeh circle glyphs with a python callback identically to when I would select the same glyphs with the TapTool manually?

Answer (score 0):

In Bokeh the `TapTool` lets you select just one glyph and mute the others. You can still select both circles in a Python callback in your example by doing `r.data_source.selected.indices = [0,1]` but with what purpose?

For multi-glyph selection you could use `BoxSelectTool`, `LassoSelectTool` or `PolySelectTool`